# How do I know how many slots are in an array after mallocing it?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, sizeof

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUM 65536
struct Test{
int t;
char args[16][65];

};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
//
struct Test *array = malloc(MAX_NUM * sizeof(struct Test*));
printf("%d", sizeof(*array));
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*array); i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
    printf(" ");
    array[i].t = 0;

}
array[421].t = 5;
printf("%d", array[421].t);
free(array);
return 0;

}
```

Hi, how do I determine how many slots of an array I have after mallocing it? When I print sizeof(*array) I get the number 1044, but when I try to run through the loop and set a test value in each slot I only get to 282 before segfaulting. What is the difference between sizeof and malloc? Why does my array only accept values up to 282 when the size of says it is 1044? Why can I edit a slot at 421 but it segfaults up to 282 in my loop? Thank you

Comment: What is `struct Key`. Does this code compile without warnings

Comment: Whoops, changed to struct Test.

Comment: I'm not sure what `table` is so  I have no idea what `sizeof(*table)` is supposed to do.

Comment: Its already written in one of the answers but you probably want `sizeof(struct Test)` in your call to malloc and not `sizeof(struct Test*)`

Comment: @m24p That is the *array.

Comment: @Brandin Yeah that changed it to not go into a segfault. I can still edit an element at array[1050].t for example, why does that not give me a seg fault?

Comment: @wheatfairies You seem to think a seg fault is an acceptable way to detect if you've accessed an invalid array index. That's the problem. C compiler assumes that you know which indexes are valid. If you go off to something invalid then it may or may not segfault, you can't trust on this to happen when you've gone off into the weeds.

Comment: @Brandin Thank you I will watch out for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
struct Test *array = malloc(MAX_NUM * sizeof(struct Test));
```

Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes! That got it up to all 1024 slots. I tried to put a value in array[1045].t to = 5 and it returned as 0 instead of getting a segmentation fault. Does this mean I allocated more spots for the array than 1024?

Comment: @wheatfairies: Accessing an array out of bounds is *undefined* behaviour. The runtime is not *obligated* to give you a seg fault. It could indicate the failure by, say, erasing your hard disk, or emailing all your files to Bolivia instead. It can do **anything** or **nothing**. If you observe nothing it means that today you got lucky.

Comment: @EricLippert I have heard the expression that C lets you go out of bounds unintentionally with dire consequences, I will be sure not to mess with any more memory out of bounds.

Comment: @wheatfairies: C not only allows you to shoot yourself in the foot, it hands you the loaded gun with the safety off, and gives you enough rope to hang yourself with in the bargain. :-)

Comment: +1 for correction  @OP: Consider a different style too.  Rather than `type *var = malloc(N * sizeof(type))`, try `type *var = malloc(N * sizeof *var)`

Answer (score 1):

For a statically-allocated array, you can use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`:

- The total amount of memory that `array` occupies is `sizeof(array)`.
- The amount of memory that a single entry occupies is `sizeof(*array)`.
- Hence, the number of entries in `array` is `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`.

For a dynamically-allocated array, however, you will have to use the value of `MAX_NUM`, since `array` is a pointer, hence `sizeof(array)` = size of a pointer, which is 4 or 8 bytes (depending on your system).

Comment: That is returning as 0 for me, but if I put it as sizeof(*array)/sizeof(array) it returns 130.

Comment: So that sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array) will read 0 if there is nothing in the array?

Comment: For a dynamically allocated array (such as the one in your question), you will have to use the value of `MAX_NUM`.

Comment: No, `sizeof(array)` in this case is the size of a pointer, which is 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The malloc is wrong: you must use sizeof(struct Test) without *.
You should also use MAX_NUM as number of iterations.

sizeof(*array) returns the size of the first element of the array so sizeof(struct Test), not the length of the array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUM 65536
struct Test{
int t;
char args[16][65];

};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
//Changed Key to Test type
struct Test *array = (Struct Test*)malloc(MAX_NUM * sizeof(struct Test));
printf("%d", sizeof(*array));
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++) {
    printf("%d", i);
    printf(" ");
    array[i].t = 0;

}
array[421].t = 5;
printf("%d", array[421].t);
free(array);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: So MAX_UID is the number of slots I have after all. I was getting some errors from that early but It seems to be working now thank you.